# I can't print my return boarding passes using the TUI website, how should I proceed?

Tags: tickets, return-tickets, tui

I have been trying to print my return boarding passes using the TUI website. I have managed to print the boarding passes for the outbound flight but cannot seem to get the return ones. How can I print the boarding pass for the return flight?

Answer (score 8):

With many airlines, online check in opens a set time before the scheduled departure time. For TUI UK, check in opens 48 hours before departure. According to [tui.co.uk](https://www.tui.co.uk/destinations/faq/when-does-online-check-in-open?catId=261&subcatId=319&docId=1155):

> If you're flying with TUI, online check-in opens 48 hours before your outward flight (departing from the UK) and is available right up until three hours before take-off. You can check-in 48 hours before your return flight as well.

In your case, you have probably checked in for the outbound flight which allows you to print your boarding pass for the outbound flight.

Check in for the return flight is probably still closed so you cannot check in for that flight yet. As such, you will have to check in for the return flight later and then you can download and print your boarding pass for that flight.

Comment: In many airports and for most airlines you can print your own boarding pass on one of their machines or get one when you drop off your luggage. (This will work if you can not print your return boarding pass while 'there'.)

Comment: @Willeke yea, I would say that's always possible but honestly I wouldn't be surprised anymore if some low cost carriers charge extra for that. Ah yes, [Ryanair charges for the privilege of checking in at the airport](https://help.ryanair.com/hc/en-lv/articles/360017824878-Boarding-Passes-Information-) and they even charge a 'Boarding Card Reissue Fee' if you have checked in online but can't present a boarding pass on paper or digitally.

Comment: @JJJ RyanAir... One of these days they will start charging for the privilege of breathing while being in one of their planes....

Comment: @Tonny Obviously that's a joke, but I wouldn't be surprised if they charged for using the A/C nozzle above the seat.

Answer (score 3):

In general I would expect that you can only print boarding passes for a flight that you have checked into.

It sounds like that you have checked into th outbound flight, and hence you can print boarding passes.

I would expect that after you check into your return flight that you will then be able to print the boarding passes.